# Publishing/Deployment tasks with CruiseControl.NET

Tags: deployment, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'd like to create a CruiseControl.NET task to mimic the publish functionality for web applications in Visual Studios.  Any suggested approaches or examples?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the RoboCopy task found in the Nightly Build of MSBuild Community Tasks http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ and excluded certain files in the copy to my release directory I created.